# How to run Angular Jasmine Tests in an Azure Pipeline?

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, google-chrome-headless

I have a need to run Jasmine tests for Angular on an Azure Pipeline.  I am using a Red Hat Enterprise Linux agent.  By default Angular uses Karma to run the tests in headless mode using Chrome.  The agent does not have Chrome so I attempt to install but it fails.  Is it possible to run the Jasmine tests without installing Chrome?

Here is the error message:

*The GPG keys listed for the "google-chrome" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.*

Here is the install script for Chrome Headless:

```
sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo << EOM
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/\$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
EOM

sudo rpm --import https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
sudo yum install -y google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Have you checked it directly on the linux machine, does the script work?